# ionic angular test PushNotifications on web browser

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am building application which will be used for mobile as well for web.
and I want to send the user message using firebase push message , for that
I am using PushNotifications  library .

***import {
Plugins,
PushNotification,
PushNotificationToken,
PushNotificationActionPerformed,
} from '@capacitor/core';***

*It works fine with mobile but on web browser it gives ERROR: Uncaught (in promise): PushNotifications does not have web implementation.*

I do understand what the message means , but I cant find if there is a web implementation for the PushNotifications , or should I use anther library?

Comment: Did you try the Firebase native plugin? I'm using here for web and works fine

Comment: I did its not working for me, i tried ever single code example on the net, no luck, download many ready  examples from github no luck

Answer (score 0):

**Notifications**

The closest capability to push notifications on the web is the notifications provided by Progressive Web Apps / service workers. If you've seen those "This website wants to send you notifications" Approve/Block notifications, you've experienced notifications on the web.

These are two great in-depth tutorials on how to enable them:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Re-engageable_Notifications_Push
- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications

Angular also provides a great service worker library, enabling which is [outlined here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

Keep in mind that browser support for notifications is limited, i.e. not all browsers support this. Most notably, Safari does not (as of the time of this post).

**Error**

As for the error, you can handle it like this, to ensure it's not thrown in the browser:

```js
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

const isPushNotificationsAvailable = Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('PushNotifications');

if (isPushNotificationsAvailable) {
   this.initPushNotifications();
}
```